# Mark a point in python plot based on condition

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the dataset df4:

```
     Cumulexr   Cumulcoun  SignB
1  43.035714   24.603175    Yes
3  71.785714   50.513539    No
0  89.107143   75.241208    No
2  100.000000  100.000000   No
```

And I am plotting them as:
`plt.plot(df4["Cumulcoun"], df4["Cumulexr"], label="4 Cl.").` But I want additionally to mark the point(with a dot) that has SignB=Yes. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can create another dataframe with rows from `df4` which have `SignB = Yes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

X = [43.035, 71.785, 89.107, 100.000]
Y = [24.603, 50.513, 75.241, 100.000]
Sign = ["Yes", 'No', 'No', 'No']

df4 = pd.DataFrame({"Cumulexr": X, "Cumulcoun": Y, "SignB": Sign})
df1 = df4.loc[df4["SignB"] == 'Yes']

plt.plot(df4["Cumulcoun"], df4["Cumulexr"])
plt.plot(df1["Cumulcoun"], df1["Cumulexr"], marker='*')

plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image]

You can set `marker='o'` to get `SignB = Yes` data points as circles/points.